# Simulate drop event with a file

Tags: firefox-addon

Users upload images to this form by dropping a file on it.

Is there a way in to trigger `drop` with a `File`/`Blob` object programmatically? Something like `MouseEvent.initMouseEvent()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

but like `initDropEvent`?

I am researching here:

- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/obj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/_tests/testing/mochitest/mochijar/chrome/mochikit/content/tests/SimpleTest/ChromeUtils.js?offset=200#254
- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/newtab/head.js?offset=0#690
- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/newtab/browser_newtab_bug765628.js#25
- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/mochitest/tests/SimpleTest/ChromeUtils.js#179 ----- this one is a mochitest and code from mochitests never ever work for me, so i think this one is useless as it needs some special environment i think

Based on this I ran this code from scratchpad witha tab with twitter loaded, and aftre clicking the "tweet" button:

```
// https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/newtab/head.js?offset=100#690
//https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/newtab/browser_newtab_bug765628.js#21

/**
 * Creates a custom drag event.
 * @param aEventType The drag event's type.
 * @param aData The event's drag data (optional).
 * @return The drag event.
 */
function createDragEvent(aContentWindow, aEventType, aData, aDataType) {
  // aDataType text/x-moz-url, text/plain, etc
  let dataTransfer = new (aContentWindow).DataTransfer("dragstart", false);
  dataTransfer.mozSetDataAt(aDataType, aData, 0);
  let event = aContentWindow.document.createEvent("DragEvents");
  event.initDragEvent(aEventType, true, true, aContentWindow, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      false, false, false, false, 0, null, dataTransfer);

  return event;
}

function sendTwitterDropEvent() {

    var aContentWindow = gBrowser.contentWindow;
    var aContentDocument = aContentWindow.document;

    var btnNewTweet = aContentDocument.getElementById('global-new-tweet-button');
    console.info('btnNewTweet:', btnNewTweet);
    if (!btnNewTweet) {
        throw new Error('global tweet button not found, probably not logged in');
    }

    btnNewTweet.click();

    var inputAddPhoto = aContentDocument.getElementById('global-tweet-dialog').querySelector('input[type=file]');
    if (!inputAddPhoto) {
        throw new Error('add photo button not found! i have no idea what could cause this');
    }

    var formTweet = aContentDocument.getElementById('global-tweet-dialog-dialog').querySelector('form'); //<form.t1-form.tweet-form has-preview has-thumbnail dynamic-photos photo-square-4>
    if (!formTweet) {
        throw new Error('tweet form not found! i have no idea what could cause this');
    }
    console.info('formTweet:', (formTweet instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNode));

    var ifaceReq = aContentWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor);
    var windowUtils = ifaceReq.getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

    var aDragData = 'site 99';
    var aDragDataType = 'plain/text';

    var event = createDragEvent(aContentWindow, "drop", aDragData, aDragDataType);
    windowUtils.dispatchDOMEventViaPresShell(formTweet, event, true);
}

sendTwitterDropEvent();
```

This should populate the tweet input with "site 99" but it doesnt. I was testing with plain text then after I get that working I was thinking of moving to `File`/`Blob`.

## Simplified non-twitter test case

Open tab with this: `data:text/html,<input id=rawr>`

Open scratchpad and run this code from scratchpad:

```
function createDragEvent(aContentWindow, aEventType, aData, aDataType) {
  // aDataType text/x-moz-url, text/plain, etc
  let dataTransfer = new (aContentWindow).DataTransfer("dragstart", false);
  dataTransfer.mozSetDataAt(aDataType, aData, 0);
  let event = aContentWindow.document.createEvent("DragEvents");
  event.initDragEvent(aEventType, true, true, aContentWindow, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      false, false, false, false, 0, null, dataTransfer);

  return event;
}

function sendTwitterDropEvent() {

    var aContentWindow = gBrowser.contentWindow;
    var aContentDocument = aContentWindow.document;

    var formTweet = aContentDocument.getElementById('rawr');
    if (!formTweet) {
        throw new Error('tweet form not found! i have no idea what could cause this');
    }
    console.info('formTweet:', (formTweet instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNode), formTweet);

    var ifaceReq = aContentWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor);
    var windowUtils = ifaceReq.getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils);

    var aDragData = 'site 99';
    var aDragDataType = 'plain/text';

    var event = createDragEvent(aContentWindow, "drop", aDragData, aDragDataType);
    var rezDrop = windowUtils.dispatchDOMEventViaPresShell(formTweet, event, true);
    console.info('rezDrop:', rezDrop);

}

sendTwitterDropEvent();
```

Comment: If your rep wasn't so high, I would be tagging it for closure.  Where is teh code that you have tried for instance ?  :-)

Comment: Haha thanks @RohitGupta for that funny comment :P I didnt try anything yet, i spoon feed others i want some spoon feeding back! i like spoon feeding it creates a love bond! hahah I dont know how to start on this one, and am trying to answer this SO topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951730/twitter-progamatically-add-photo